# How to output url time string as text instead of video?

Tags: javascript

I have some code that outputs a time string into a video. I know how to make it output as video or image but I want it to just show up as plain text so I can make a list of live-updating URLs based on the current time.

Currently it is set to "video.r" which adds the time to a "

So that instead of doing:

```
<video class="r" src="https://mywebsite.com/2019102618URLDATE?=201910261841?New.mp4" type="video/x-flv" width="350"></video>
```

It would just output as:

```
https://mywebsite.com/2019102618URLDATE?=201910261841?New.mp4
```

Here's the code for it.

HTML

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="screen.js"></script>

        <center><h1> URL List </h1></center>
<video class="r" src="https://mywebsite.com/" type="video/x-flv" type="video/mp4" width="350"></video>
```

JS

```js
$(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var ss = today.getSeconds();
  var nn = today.getMinutes() * 60 - 90; //60 second delay
  var nm = today.getMinutes();
  var hh = today.getUTCHours();
  var dd = today.getUTCDate();
  var mm = today.getUTCMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getUTCFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }
  if (hh < 10) {
    hh = '0' + hh
  }
  if (nm < 10) {
    nm = '0' + nm
  }
  var minsec = nn + ss + 30

  var today = yyyy + '' + mm + '' + dd + '' + hh +  'URLDATE?=' + yyyy + '' + mm + '' + dd + '' + hh + nm +  '?New.mp4' ;
  $('video.r').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
      $(this).attr("src", url + today);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("src", url + today);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I understand what you want is having a link, which points to an URL like the one you posted.

If so, then it is pretty simple. You already a function that builds the URL, now instead of using this URL as a video's `src` attribute, you can use it as a link's `href` attribute:

**Edit:** Or, if you just want to list URLs as plain text, simply use the link's `innerHTML` attribute instead of `href` in the below solution.

```js
$(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var ss = today.getSeconds();
  var nn = today.getMinutes() * 60 - 90; //60 second delay
  var nm = today.getMinutes();
  var hh = today.getUTCHours();
  var dd = today.getUTCDate();
  var mm = today.getUTCMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getUTCFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }
  if (hh < 10) {
    hh = '0' + hh
  }
  if (nm < 10) {
    nm = '0' + nm
  }
  var minsec = nn + ss + 30

  var today = yyyy + '' + mm + '' + dd + '' + hh +  'URLDATE?=' + yyyy + '' + mm + '' + dd + '' + hh + nm +  '?New.mp4' ;
  $('a.r').each(function() { //here change "video.r" to "a.r"
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); //and here "src" becomes "href"
    if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
      $(this).attr("href", url + today);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("href", url + today);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="screen.js"></script>

        <center><h1> URL List </h1></center>
<a class="r" href="https://mywebsite.com/">Link</a>
```

Comment: Perfect, almost exactly what I needed. I was looking for what your edited stated where it shows as plain text instead of as a link. I changed href to innerHTML in the javascript, but what would I change it to in the HTML?